# Is the function 'dlopen()' private API?

Tags: ios, dynamic-linking, dlopen, dynamic-library

I want use function 'dlopen()' to invoke a dynamic library on iOS platform, is the function 'dlopen()' private API?

Comment: no. Its mentioned in docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW3

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've had success using dlopen on iOS for years.  In my use case, I use dlopen to load public system frameworks on demand instead of having them loaded on app launch.  Works great!

[EDIT] - as of iOS 8, extensions and shared frameworks are prohibited from using `dlopen`, however the application itself can still use `dlopen` (and is now documented as being supported for not only Apple frameworks, but custom frameworks too).  See the **Deploying a Containing App to Older Versions of iOS** section in [this Apple doc](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329080836/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensibilityPG.pdf).

[EDIT] - contrived example

```
#import <dlfcn.h>

void printApplicationState()
{
    Class UIApplicationClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIApplication");
    if (Nil == UIApplicationClass) {
        void *handle = dlopen("System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit", RTLD_NOW);
        if (handle) {
            UIApplicationClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIApplication");
            assert(UIApplicationClass != Nil);
            NSInteger applicationState = [UIApplicationClass applicationState];
            printf("app state: %ti\n", applicationState);
            if (0 != dlclose(handle)) {
                printf("dlclose failed! %s\n", dlerror());
            }
        } else {
            printf("dlopen failed! %s\n", dlerror());
        }
    } else {
        printf("app state: %ti\n", [UIApplicationClass applicationState]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't run into any problems with App Store rejections?

Comment: @DavidLiu - nope, no problems.  You can't link with any unsigned binaries, but there is no issue using dlopen with OS provided public frameworks or dynamic libraries.

This may have changed, but I've worked at 2 companies and done this: 1 with roughtly 1.5 million MAU and 1 with 150 million MAU.

Comment: Can you help me with example? How to load dynamic framework using dlopen?

Comment: `void* handle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit", RTLD_NOW);` and then you can unload (decrement the load count by 1) by calling `dlclose(handle);`.  Be sure to read the docs for more info. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlopen.3.html

Comment: @NSProgrammer how are you able to use @imports/#imports?  It seems a good way for you to skip loading hundreds of shared dylibs, but I am not sure how you would be able to compile and usage of UIKit for example... Any ideas?

Comment: @iOSAddicted the imports are not the issue, it's the linker that will be the issue.  Calling a symbol of a dylib will force the link to be resolved at link time which won't be the case with dyld loading.  The solution is to use indirection -- NSClassFromString for example and NSSelectorFromString.  For enums, you're fine, but for extern constants you'll need to duplicate the value to a var/const local to your binary.  It's a pain, but doable.