# Using dlopen() to load ios Embedded framework on runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode8

I recently learned about App Extensions on iOS platform. I have a framework which i want to integrate with an application that supports ios 7 as well. I learned that i can check the ios version on runtime and then load the framework on runtime.
I researched about it and there are some answers where it is written that you cannot use dlopen() command anymore because the application will be rejected on App store. But all those answers are pretty old.

Can i use dlopen() command to load the dynamic framework at runtime? if yes, can anyone show me how to use it?

Comment: It looks like you still cannot use it (this dates from May 2017 so it's not too old: https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP/issues/24). There is some code here, but the guidance is not not use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530701/is-the-function-dlopen-private-api